# How to export Multiple ag grids to single excel with each ag grid data as a different worksheet in excel in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I have to export 2 ag grids into a single excel sheet. with each ag grid data corresponding to a worksheet in excel

I tried this way but getsheetdataforexcel is not available in angularjs or i have to install something for that? I have 2 ag grids in 1 screen. USAOptions and IndiaOptions. I am using old angularJS. It seems i don't have getSheetDataForExcel in angularJS ag grid. I get error getSheetDataForExcel is not a function. is there a way?

```
 vm.exportData = function (exportType) {
    

    var spreadsheets = [
      vm.USAOptions.api.getSheetDataForExcel({
        sheetName: "USA",
      }),
      vm.IndiaOptions.api.getSheetDataForExcel({
        sheetName: "INDIA",
      })
    ];

    vm.USAOptions.api.exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel({
      data: spreadsheets,
      fileName: 'Countries.xlsx'
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`getRowNodeId`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-ids/) and [`getDisplayedRowCount`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/rendering-api/) to manually create the data for each worksheet, followed by using [`exportDataAsExcel`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/excel-export/) for exporting to Excel.

Although, it would help to know which version of Charts/Grids you are using.
For instance, after [Grid v27.1.0/Charts 5.10](https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=27.1.0), `gridOptions.immutableData` and `gridOptions.getRowNodeId()` are deprecated. Instead, implement `getRowId()`, and the grid will then also treat the data as immutable data automatically.

Still, that approach provides more control over which rows are exported and can be useful if you need to manipulate or format the data differently for each grid before exporting.

```js
vm.exportData = function () {
  // Function to manually extract data from a grid
  function extractGridData(gridOptions) {
    var rowData = [];
    var rowCount = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount();
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var rowNode = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(i);
      rowData.push(rowNode.data);
    }
    return rowData;
  }

  // Extracting data from both grids
  var USAData = extractGridData(vm.USAOptions);
  var IndiaData = extractGridData(vm.IndiaOptions);

  // Preparing data for export
  var exportData = [
    {
      name: "USA",
      data: USAData
    },
    {
      name: "INDIA",
      data: IndiaData
    }
  ];

  // Exporting to Excel
  vm.USAOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel({
    data: exportData,
    fileName: 'Countries.xlsx'
  });
};
```

`extractGridData` function iterates through each row of the grid and constructs an array of row data. `USAData` and `IndiaData` hold the data from the respective grids. `exportDataAsExcel` is called with an array containing the data for each sheet.

---

> It still exports only `USAData`, not `IndiaData`...
> I would like to have `USAData` in 1 sheet of Excel and IndiaData in another sheet of the same Excel.

Given the capabilities of the AG Grid API and the requirements for exporting multiple sheets, if you are using a version of AG Grid that supports the [`getSheetDataForExcel` method](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-export-getSheetDataForExcel) natively, you can use it to format the grid data appropriately for Excel export, simplifying the process significantly.

Your `exportData` function would then be:

```js
vm.exportData = function () {
  // Using AG Grid's built-in method to prepare data for Excel export
  var USAWorksheetData = vm.USAOptions.api.getSheetDataForExcel({ sheetName: "USA" });
  var IndiaWorksheetData = vm.IndiaOptions.api.getSheetDataForExcel({ sheetName: "INDIA" });

  // Parameters for exporting multiple sheets
  var multipleSheetsParams = {
    author: "AG Grid",
    data: [USAWorksheetData, IndiaWorksheetData],
    fileName: 'Countries.xlsx'
  };

  // Exporting to Excel with multiple sheets
  vm.USAOptions.api.exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel(multipleSheetsParams);
};
```

The custom `getSheetDataForExcel` function is removed, as AG Grid's own `getSheetDataForExcel` method is used directly.
`USAWorksheetData` and `IndiaWorksheetData` are obtained by calling `getSheetDataForExcel` on each grid instance (`vm.USAOptions` and `vm.IndiaOptions`).
The `multipleSheetsParams` object is prepared according to the `ExcelExportMultipleSheetParams` interface, and `exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel` is called to perform the export.

---

> My ag grid version is 2.1.31 and i am using angular js version 4.4.7.  I don't have getSheetDataForExcel  and exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel  functions...
> What can I do? My project cannot be upgraded to new angular. It has to be angularJs. Not sure what higher ag grid version i compatible with angular JS

If you are using AG Grid version 2.1.31 with AngularJS 4.4.7 and do not have access to `getSheetDataForExcel` and `exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel` functions, you will need to adopt a different approach to export multiple AG Grids to separate sheets in an Excel file.

Since the newer AG Grid functionalities are not available in your version, you can manually construct the data for Excel export. That would mean collecting the data from each grid, converting it to a format compatible with Excel, and then using a third-party library like `xlsx` (SheetJS) to create the Excel file with multiple sheets.
(make sure you have the `xlsx` library included in your project. You can include it via a script tag or install it via npm/yarn if your project setup allows it.)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
```

Then, use the in your AngularJS controller:

```js
vm.exportData = function () {
  // Function to extract grid data
  function extractGridData(gridOptions) {
    var rowData = [];
    gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function(node) {
      rowData.push(node.data);
    });
    return rowData;
  }

  // Extract data from both grids
  var USAData = extractGridData(vm.USAOptions);
  var IndiaData = extractGridData(vm.IndiaOptions);

  // Function to convert data to worksheet format
  function sheetFromArrayOfArrays(data) {
    var worksheet = {};
    var range = {s: {c:0, r:0}, e: {c:data[0].length, r:data.length }};
    for(var R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {
      for(var C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {
        if(data[R][C] == null) continue;
        var cell = {v: data[R][C]};
        var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C,r:R});
        if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
        else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
        else cell.t = 's';
        worksheet[cell_ref] = cell;
      }
    }
    worksheet['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
    return worksheet;
  }

  // Create worksheet for each grid
  var USASheet = sheetFromArrayOfArrays(USAData);
  var IndiaSheet = sheetFromArrayOfArrays(IndiaData);

  // Create new workbook and add the sheets
  var workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, USASheet, 'USA');
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, IndiaSheet, 'India');

  // Export the workbook
  XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'Countries.xlsx');
};
```

`extractGridData` function would gathers data from each grid. `sheetFromArrayOfArrays` converts the data into a format suitable for SheetJS (`xlsx`).
A new workbook is created, and each sheet is appended to this workbook. Finally, `XLSX.writeFile` is used to generate and download the Excel file.

Comment: It looked promising. but it still exports only USAData, not IndiaData... i would like to have USAData in 1 sheet of excel and IndiaData in another sheet of same excel

Comment: My ag grid version is 2.1.31 and i am using angular js version 4.4.7.  i don't have getSheetDataForExcel  and exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel  functions.. what can i do? my project cannot be upgraded to new angular. it has to be angularJs. not sure what higher ag grid version i compatible with angular JS

Comment: @NoStressDeveloper OK. I have edited the answer to propose a third alternative.